# executing assembly within a function in c++

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

```
    
long getesp() {  
    __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");  
    }  

    void main() {  
    printf("%08X\n",getesp()+4);  
    }
```

why does esp points to value before the stack frame is setup and does it makes any difference between with the code below?

```
   
void main() {    
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");    
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After i did a `gcc -S file.c`

```
getesp:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $4, %esp
#APP
# 4 "xxt.c" 1
    movl %esp,%eax
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    leave
    ret


main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $20, %esp
    call    getesp
    addl    $4, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    printf
    addl    $20, %esp
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
```

The `getesp` has a `pushl` which manipulates the `esp` and gets the manipulated `esp` in `eax` with the inline and as well as in `ebp`.

Making a function call to fetch the stack pointer and getting it inside the `main` is definitely different, and it differs by 12 bytes (in this specific case). This is because when you execute the `call` pushes the `eip` (if not intersegment, and for linux/unix normal program execution it is only `eip`) (need citation), next inside the `getesp` function there is another `push` with `ebp` and after that the stack pointer is subtracted by 4. Because the `eip` and `ebp` are of 4 bytes, so the total difference is now 12 bytes. Which actually we can see in the function call version.

Without the function call there is no pushing of `eip` and other `esp` manipulation, so we get the `esp` value after the main setup.

I am not comfortable with AT&T so here is the same code in Intel syntax and an Intex syntax asm dump below. Note that in the `printf` call for the `__asm__` inside the main value got into `a` there is no push or other `esp` modification so, the `__asm__` inside main gets the `esp` value which was set in the main by the `sub     esp, 20` line. Where as the value we get by calling `getesp` is the (what you are expecting) - 12 , as described above.

The C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;

long getesp() {
__asm__("mov a, esp");
}

int main(void) 
{

    __asm__("mov a,esp");
    printf("%08X\n",a);

    getesp ();
    printf("%08X\n",a);
}
```

The output is in my case for the specific run:

```
BF855D00
BF855CF4
```

The intel syntax dump is:

```
getesp:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4
#APP
# 7 "xt.c" 1
    mov a, esp
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    leave
    ret


main:
    lea     ecx, [esp+4]
    and     esp, -16
    push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    sub     esp, 20
#APP
# 12 "xt.c" 1
    mov a,esp
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR a
    mov     DWORD PTR [esp+4], eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    printf
    call    getesp
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR a
    mov     DWORD PTR [esp+4], eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    call    printf
    add     esp, 20
    pop     ecx
    pop     ebp
    lea     esp, [ecx-4]
    ret
```

I hope this helps.