# getting the starting address of stack

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [executing assembly within a function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009056/executing-assembly-within-a-function-in-c)

```
long getesp() {  
__asm__("movl %esp,%eax");  
}  

void main() {  
printf("%08X\n",getesp()+4);  
}
```

why is the esp printed is before the stack is set up?(before the pushl %ebp, movl %esp,%ebp)
thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't write 'void main( )' -- instead, write '**int main( int argc, char **argv )** '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: there is no need for a frame, so none is allocated in getesp. The particulars depend on the compiler and compiler flags you are using.